Strongswan VPN client and server configuration, both running Debian
Please help to configure Strongswan VPN client and server both runing  Debian.
Can't connect them. What is wrong?
Below my server/client configuration and status output, where:
aaa.bbb.168.117 - server IP
xxx.yyy.96.226 - client IP
192.168 - client local network

My server configuration:
conn %default
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes256-sha256-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha256!
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    leftauth=pubkey
    leftcert=serverCert.pem
    leftid=@aaa.bbb.168.117
    right=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity
    auto=add

My server ipsec.secrets:
John : EAP "password"

My server ipsec status output:
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none

My server systemctl status strong swan-starter output:
strongswan-starter.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/strongswan-starter.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-08-09 09:32:25 UTC; 5h 14min ago
   Main PID: 1364182 (starter)
      Tasks: 18 (limit: 1150)
     Memory: 3.8M
        CPU: 28ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/strongswan-starter.service
             ├─1364182 /usr/lib/ipsec/starter --daemon charon --nofork
             └─1364186 /usr/lib/ipsec/charon --debug-ike 2 --debug-knl 2 --debug-cfg 2

Aug 09 14:02:44 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 06[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Aug 09 14:02:44 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 06[NET] sending packet: from aaa.bbb.168.117[4500] to 157.245.115.28[38053] (>
Aug 09 14:02:44 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 06[IKE] IKE_SA (unnamed)[5] state change: CREATED => DESTROYING
Aug 09 14:18:19 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 08[NET] received packet: from xxx.yyy.96.226[500] to aaa.bbb.168.117[500] (120>
Aug 09 14:18:19 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 08[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(>
Aug 09 14:18:19 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 08[CFG] looking for an IKEv2 config for aaa.bbb.168.117...xxx.yyy.96.226
Aug 09 14:18:19 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 08[IKE] no IKE config found for aaa.bbb.168.117...xxx.yyy.96.226, sending NO_P>
Aug 09 14:18:19 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 08[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Aug 09 14:18:19 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 08[NET] sending packet: from aaa.bbb.168.117[500] to xxx.yyy.96.226[500] (36 b>
Aug 09 14:18:19 debian-DTX-1gb charon[1364186]: 08[IKE] IKE_SA (unnamed)[6] state change: CREATED => DESTROYING

My client configuration:
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

config setup
    charondebug="ike 2, knl 2, cfg 2"

conn myvpn
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes256-sha256-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha256!
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    auto=start
    leftsourceip=%config
    leftauth=eap-mschapv2
    eap_identity=dk
    right=aaa.bbb.168.117
    rightid=@aaa.bbb.168.117
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    rightauth=pubkey
    rightca="C=US, O=MyVPN, CN=MyVPN CA"

My client ipsec.secrets:
John : EAP "password"

My client ipsec status output:
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none

My client systemctl status strong swan-starter output:
strongswan-starter.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/strongswan-starter.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-08-09 17:02:20 EDT; 9min ago
   Main PID: 3365 (starter)
      Tasks: 18 (limit: 4423)
     Memory: 3.8M
        CPU: 73ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/strongswan-starter.service
             ├─3365 /usr/lib/ipsec/starter --daemon charon --nofork
             └─3369 /usr/lib/ipsec/charon --debug-ike 2 --debug-knl 2 --debug-cfg 2

Aug 09 17:02:20 elf ipsec[3369]: 08[IKE] IKE_SA myvpn[1] state change: CREATED => CONNECTING
Aug 09 17:02:20 elf ipsec[3369]: 08[CFG] configured proposals: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_1024
Aug 09 17:02:20 elf ipsec[3369]: 08[CFG] sending supported signature hash algorithms: sha256 sha384 sha512 identity
Aug 09 17:02:20 elf ipsec[3369]: 08[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Aug 09 17:02:20 elf ipsec[3369]: 08[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.1.108[500] to aaa.bbb.168.117[500] (336 bytes)
Aug 09 17:02:20 elf ipsec[3369]: 10[NET] received packet: from aaa.bbb.168.117[500] to 192.168.1.108[500] (36 bytes)
Aug 09 17:02:20 elf ipsec[3369]: 10[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Aug 09 17:02:20 elf ipsec[3369]: 10[IKE] received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error
Aug 09 17:02:20 elf ipsec[3369]: 10[CFG] configured proposals: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_1024
Aug 09 17:02:20 elf charon[3369]: 10[IKE] IKE_SA myvpn[1] state change: CONNECTING => DESTROYING

